# How to remove browser autoscroll to a div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

In my webpage, I am using a vertical accordion in the centre to list some contents. When the page is loaded, the accordion is in the middle. But when a user clicks on the accordion tab, the whole page scrolls up, making the accordion tab to be on the top of browser. How can I avoid this reaction. I want users to stay on the page part itself with out having an automatic scroll. Is there any solution?

When the user clicks on the accordion tab, the page URL becomes,
http://web.com/#tab_1. But I cant remove the id from accordion as it needs ID for functioning. Any other solution?

Comment: Use preventDefault or Return False on the click handler!

Comment: THIS IS THE SOURCE OF ACCORDION : http://webdevtuts.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/demo/vertical_accordion/index.html

Comment: Add some code to your question. Don't make everyone else hunt around and GUESS how you have implemented code from an example page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, you should prevent the default action for clicking the links (namely, scrolling to the anchor). Some pseudocode since I don't know how your accordion is set up:

```
$("#accordion a").click(function(e)) {
  e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the scrolling from occuring
  $("#accordion").activate($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: The accordion is not using jquery. its using css3. Here is the link Demo :http://webdevtuts.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/demo/vertical_accordion/index.html and documentation : http://www.webdevtuts.net/css/create-a-vertical-accordion-slider-using-pure-css3-and-html/

Comment: Then why did you use Java and jQuery tags for your question, and not CSS tags ?

Comment: @interrobang : I am using http://webdevtuts.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/demo/vertical_accordion/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` use `preventDefault` it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a straightforward CSS-based way to avoid the fact that the :target pseudo-selector comes with the default browser behavior for URL fragment links, which is to scroll to the element in question. You're going to have to add this with JS, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, it is that the page goes to the top on clicks, personally i always add this to stop that auto scroll ting.

Add the script

```
<%--Magic Script that maintains position on partial rendering and click--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo = function (x, y) {
        return true;
    }
</script>
```